# Writes, Deletes, but won't read text file

Tags: python

I just started learning python today. This is a simple script to either read, write one line to, or delete a text file. It writes and deletes just fine, but when choosing the 'r' (read) option i just get the error:

> IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

What am I missing here...?

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

target = open(filename, 'w')

option = raw_input('What to do? (r/d/w)')

if option == 'r':   
    print(target.read())

if option == 'd':
    target.truncate()
    target.close()  

if option == 'w':
    print('Input new content')
    content = raw_input('>')
    target.write(content)
    target.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've opened the file in write mode, so you can't perform read on it. And secondly `'w'` automatically truncates the file, so your truncate operation is useless.
You can use `r+` mode here:

```
target = open(filename, 'r+')
```

> 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing

Use the `with` statement while opening the file, it automatically closes the file for you:

```
option = raw_input('What to do? (r/d/w)')

with  open(filename, "r+")  as target:
    if option == 'r':
        print(target.read())

    elif option == 'd':
        target.truncate()

    elif option == 'w':
        print('Input new content')
        content = raw_input('>')
        target.write(content)
```

As @abarnert has suggested it'll be better to open the file as per the mode entered by user, because read only files may raise error with `'r+'` mode in first place:

```
option = raw_input('What to do? (r/d/w)')

if option == 'r':
    with open(filename,option) as target:
        print(target.read())

elif option == 'd':
    #for read only files use Exception handling to catch the errors
    with open(filename,'w') as target:
        pass

elif option == 'w':
    #for read only files use Exception handling to catch the errors
    print('Input new content')
    content = raw_input('>')
    with open(filename,option) as target:
        target.write(content)
```

Comment: This answers what the OP asked (and very nicely). But it's worth pointing out that it might be better to open the file in a different mode depending on `option`. That way, you can, e.g., read files on a CD.